# Loop through classes and stop when you get to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with looping. I was using .each with jquery but unable to figure this out. Basically I am looking to loop through classes starting with the start class and finishing when I get to the stop class, changing the color of only the classes in between start and stop.

```
<ul>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label start">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label stop">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe something in combination with [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

Comment: What code do you have so far? We don't do your work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @elclanrs said, use `nextUntil`:

```
$('.start').nextUntil('.stop').each(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.start').nextUntil('.stop')` will do an exclusive between, meaning it excludes `.start` and `.stop`.

If you want an inclusive between, use `$('.start').nextUntil('.stop + *').addBack()`.

**Example:**

```js
$('.start').nextUntil('.stop + *').addBack().css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label start">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label stop">Label 1</li>
 <li class="label">Label 1</li>
</ul>
```